# If I switch to Casual or Phoenix mode, will I get my fallen units back?

Tags: nintendo-3ds-3dsxl-2ds, fire-emblem-fates

In Fire Emblem Fates, you can choose between Classic, Casual, and Phoenix game modes. In Classic, your units have permadeath, but in Casual and Phoenix they'll come back. If I start out with Classic, lose unit XYZ, and switch to Casual or Phoenix, will I get unit XYZ back?

Comment: How exactly would you switch between the different modes? My understanding was that once you created an account within a certain mode, you can't change it until you beat the game and you are replaying.

Comment: I'm not sure if this refers to the game before you beat it, but: http://www.gamefaqs.com/boards/141838-fire-emblem-fates-birthright/73329313

Comment: Have you tried doing as that forum post suggested?

Comment: @Cyberson To be completely honest, I haven't bought the game yet. I heard about the different modes, and I was just curious. I was hoping someone who has the game knew already.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it appears that switching mode to Casual or Phoenix will resurrect the characters you lost in previous chapters ([source](http://www.gamefaqs.com/boards/114533-fire-emblem-fates-conquest/73185718?page=1#11)).

This apparently only affects standard characters on your game path, though. Units obtained through capture or the Einherjar shop do not come back after switching from Classic mode.